# Visual Studio 2013 in aspx source jump to correct place in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way, when editing ASPX source, to jump to the correct function in the code behind?

For example: If I right-click there is a View Code option
[image: Right click]

But this just takes you to the last position in the code behind, I'd like to be at the relevant place, in this case the itemSearchButton_Click event:
[image: Code behind]

Is this possible, maybe with an extension?
I've searched but not found anything.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a hotkey script using AutoHotkey to perform this for me, and assigned it to Windowskey-F7

```
#F7::
SendInput ^w^c{F7}^{Home}^f{Tab 6}{Home}+{Tab 6}^a{Del}^v{Esc}
return
```